# Cannot invoke 'CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage' with an argument list of type '(Unmanaged<CFHTTPMessage>!)'

Tags: ios, swift, cfnetwork

I followed with the Apple's documentation, but in Swift, then I came across this error.

```
let url = "http://www.apple.com"
let myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, nil);

let myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, "GET", myURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1)
let mySerializedRequest = CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(myRequest)
```

Cannot invoke 'CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage' with an argument list of type '(Unmanaged< CFHTTPMessage>!)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your working code:

```
let url = "http://www.apple.com"
let myURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, nil)
let myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, "GET", myURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1).takeRetainedValue()
let mySerializedRequest = CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(myRequest).takeRetainedValue()
```

You use `takeRetainedValue` when the unmanaged object has a `+1` retain count and you want ARC to take care of releasing the object when you're done.

In your case the definition of `CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage` is:

```
func CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage(message: CFHTTPMessage!) -> Unmanaged<CFData>!
```

So you have to pass the argument of type `CFHTTPMessage` and your `myRequest` type without using `takeRetainedValue()` is `Unmanaged<CFHTTPMessage>!` so `CFHTTPMessageCopySerializedMessage` will never accept it thats why you have to add `takeRetainedValue()` at last like this:

```
let myRequest = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, "GET", myURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1).takeRetainedValue()
```

And it will work fine.